# Too much space in svg text

Tags: css, svg

I am using a logo in svg.
All is good but I have this part of text:

```
<text style="-inkscape-font-specification:LetterGothicStd" transform="matrix(1.33333 0 0 .86152 979.54 1299.56)" font-weight="400" font-size="107.97" font-family="Letter Gothic Std" fill="#28430a">
    <tspan y="0" x="0 64.779419 129.55884 194.33826 259.11768 323.89709 388.67651 453.45593 518.23535 583.01477 647.79419 712.57361 777.35303 842.13245 906.91187 971.69128 1036.4707">C R E A T I O N S</tspan>
  </text>
```

And for some reason between the "I" and the "O" there is too mush space. No matter what size I put it with or without space it always has extra space. What can it be? I am quite new to SVG.

Comment: Adjust the x values to have whatever space you want.

Comment: I am doing this but the differences between letters are 64.779419 and that is the difference between the "I" and the "O" but even though is bigger than the others

Comment: so make that distance smaller between those particular letters if that's what you want.